# Can you create check boxes in the command palette in Visual Studio Code

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

I am thinking about creating an extension in Visual Studio Code. However, I originally wanted to create a dialog with entries and check boxes. It seems that it is not possible to make custom UI dialogs and that everything runs through the command palette. Is there a way to have check boxes in the command palette for an extension?

From what I've seen through digging into different tutorials and documentation check boxes seem like it is impossible to implement in Visual Studio Code.

Comment: with the command palette you can start a WebView and in there you have all the HTML/JavaScript you want. A WebView tab works like a normal Web browser tab

Comment: You get checkboxes in a QuickPick (if you selectMany option) and you can fill it with whatever string content you want.  See, for example, https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ArturoDent.command-alias